# Coldfusion 302 redirect on http() request

Tags: redirect, coldfusion, http-headers

I am trying to log in to a website using my application in coldfusion. It was working perfect until the website I get data from, changed their url after login to redirect to some other url. 
I have `redirect = false` set in the `http()` request. My application on `http` request gives me everything but `location` from the `http request "Responseheader"` When I try to manually log in to the website it has a `location` set to redirect URL in the `POST response header`. I don't understand why `http` request fails to get the `location` response header. I use `coldfusion 11 update 3` and website I an trying to get data from is on `Microsoft IIS 7.5`

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that ColdFusion's cfhttp call will follow redirects by default. Try adding the `redirect=false` argument to you cfhttp call. You should then be able to see the `Location` key in the `Responseheader`.

In cfscript this would be:

```
httpService = new http(); 
httpService.setRedirect(false);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have `redirect=false` in the http request. But I still am not able to figure out why this happens.

Comment: user2067888 - Can you show us some code then and tell us what you've already tried so we don't suggest things you've already done.